# IdentityServer3 and JWT ValidateIssuerSigningKey

Tags: javascript, c#, owin, identityserver3

I'm accessing a standard IdentityServer3 host app (ASP.NET WebApi 2).

I'm using the JavaScript way to get a token from IdSvr [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient-Simple/index.html#L43)

I then take that JWT add it to the authorisation request header and will attempt to process that in my app.

I use the: `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` middleware to validate this token. Firstly is this correct?

I have tried:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
    new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "myscope" },
            IssuerName = "My Issuer"
        });
```

But I get an error, "can't read token because it's not a valid base64 format".

With `UseJwt...` I get an error in our UAT environment about can't validate issuer signing key because I'm trying to use dev test one (which means I need the UAT cert). However, our other apps use `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions())` and don't seem to have to worry about this issuer signing key....

Am I missing something in the way I'm trying to read and validate this token or shall I continue down my path with creating a `X509SecurityKey()` using the public key?

All our apps work with HTTPS so everything is communicated using TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to set the Authority property to point to the identity server base URL. This way the certificate (amongst other things) is downloaded from the discovery document, and the middleware can configure itself automatically.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting a token from IdSrv through the client and posting it to my web app, my web app then checks the token : if it is good it will send a new token back down the line, so `app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` will only work for one token!

Comment: This new token is what the client will use to authenticate all it's requests with the web app